# Unable to execute cell -script using java process executor

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I am trying to run shell script using java process executor.It works fine for me when i am using it for PING command , however unable to produce any impact over DUMP command. Here is the code which one i am trying.

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;

  public class ExecuteShellComand {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecuteShellComand obj = new ExecuteShellComand();

    String domainName = "www.google.com";
    String command1 = "ping -c 3 " + domainName;
    String command = "pg_dump -U kalculate Kalculate_4.1_final -f testfinal11.sql";
    String output = obj.executeCommand(command1);
    obj.executeCommand(command);
    System.out.println(output);

}

private String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = 
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();

   }

}
```

Here `obj.executeCommand(command);` is not making any impact.Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to separate the parameters into separate variables or strings.

Example:

From:

```
String command1 = "ping -c 3 " + domainName;  
String command = "pg_dump -U kalculate Kalculate_4.1_final -f testfinal11.sql";  
String output = obj.executeCommand(command1);
```

To:

```
String command1 = "ping";  
String parameter01 = "-c";  
String parameter02 = "3";  
String output = obj.executeCommand(command1, parameter01, parameter02, domainName);
```